# jQuery ConnectedSortable Double Click

Tags: jquery

I have two lists connected with connectedSortable in jQuery UI but I want to add a feature of the ability to double click on an item and have it move to the other list but I don't really know how to go about it.

Comment: You need to bind a click event to the element you want to move and the append it to the list you need it be show in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  $j('#list-one li').dblclick(function() {
    var litem = $j(this).clone();
    litem.appendTo($j('#list-two'));
    $j(this).remove();
  });
```

Ended up with something like this